# error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const wchar_t*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'

Tags: eclipse, opencl

I am getting following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const wchar_t*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
```

My compiling command is

```
g++ -I"C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include" -I"C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include\common" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  **-std=c++11** -MMD -MP -MF"src/oclobject.d" -MT"src/oclobject.o" -o "src/oclobject.o" "../src/oclobject.cpp"
```

I am checking this on eclipse Oxygen with cygwinx64 compiler for compiling Intel OCL sample applications.

---

Comment: Could you show your sourcecode please?

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using?